# Node and edge outline?

Tags: cytoscape.js

In `cytoscape.js` halo outlines can be set for text.  Can this effect also be applied to nodes and edges?  I've tried experimenting with the keyword, but it didn't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can put borders on nodes, though they are centred on the stroke of the shape rather than an outline. -Max